# Google tracking with Measurement protocol for events

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

First time on the forums so please be nice lol.

Having some issues with measurement protocol for events, Im currently embbeding a tracking code.

> img style="visibility:hidden;display:none;" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-97225468-1&cid=555&dp=Wolf%Landing%Page&ec=video&ea=Play&el=wolf%video playing&cn=Wolf%Campaign&cs=Interm%lp

Now im currently trying to track when a Youtube video starts and ends on a client website, I am not able to put JS onto the page. Just a pixel or static pixel, which leads me to this bit of code above. I am able to get the details of the event on GA, but it does not let me know if the video is played or not. Just records it as a hit regardless, I am also looking to do the same with clicks on another page with events but no luck there.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: If you cant add code to the page i am not sure you are going to be able to detect that a user clicked play.   What you are doing now is what is used for email tracking  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email